# Footer Widget div container showing duplicate container inside of it not sure why

Tags: css, wordpress, widget

Can anyone tell me why im getting the duplicate container inside my footer widget? I put a border around the container div it to make it easier to see.

http://covalier.com/covalierbranded/

CSS:

```
 #footer-widget0 {
        width: 240px;
        min-height: 300px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
        padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
        border: solid 1px #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        line-height: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #footer-widget0 a {
        color: #7c0000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: 900;
    }

    #footer-widget0 a:hover {
        color: #f0b901;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="Footer">
            <div id="FooterHeader"></div>

                <div id="footer-widgets"><!--container-->

                    <div id="footer-widget0">
                    <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('footer-0') ) : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>



                    <div style="clear: both"></div>
                </div>


                <footer id="footer" class="source-org vcard copyright" role="contentinfo">
                    <small>&copy;<?php echo date("Y"); echo " "; bloginfo('name'); ?></small>
                </footer>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML, CSS and scripts, because from what I can see it look like you have just made a parent div and a child div with the same class name, But I'm not sure if that is just how you wrote it or if it is a bug on publish?

Comment: Remove one of the `<div id="footer-widfget0">` wrappers and you're golden.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu your stating the very obvious. In my css, there is only 1 instance that i have written. It seems the other one is being dynamically generated and i don't know why, this has never happened to me before.

Comment: im not trying to write a new rule on top of the one wordpress writes though. Im only trying to style the existing wordpress rule. So if im only styling it, i still don't understand why its spitting it twice and im only writing it once. Ive done this countless times for other websites and this is the FIRST time im ever having this issue.

Comment: I agree that I'm stating the obvious. I also realize you don't like that but I don't know how I can help more than explaining what's going on and how you can remedy it. Have a bit of trust. Remove the wrapper and see what happens. Keep in mind that, even if not valid markup, duplicate ids and duplicated wrappers are the sort of problem which can go unnoticed a lot of times in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The problem after much exploration was in the functions.php file. I had to change:

```
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Footer Widget 0',
'id'        => 'footer-0',
'description' => 'First footer widget area',
'before_widget' => '<div id="footer-widget0">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h2>',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
```

to

```
register_sidebar(array(
'name' => 'Footer Widget 0',
'id'        => 'footer-0',
'description' => 'First footer widget area',
'before_widget' => '<div id="">',
'after_widget' => '</div>',
'before_title' => '<h2>',
'after_title' => '</h2>',
));
```

that solved the issue

Comment: You're not supposed to give your widget area a wrapper with an `id`, because WP automatically gives it one, based on the widget area id. Now you have `<div id="footer-0"><div id="">...content</div></div>`, instead of just `<div id="footer-0">...content</div>`. You're still outputting the extra wrapper, it's just that you have given it an empty `id`.